# Trying to subtract the integers from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

Hello I am trying to finish this small exercise if anyone could help...

Having this dictionairy `{'101': ['90', '20'], '102': ['70', '50']}`

I am trying to subtract 90- 20 and 70 - 50 but this is how far I am, and feel stuck now..

```
 for(students, marks) in dict.items():
  # check if all marks are digits if not throw error
  for mark in marks:
    if mark.isdigit() == False:
      raise ValueError('Values are not correct.')
    if mark.isdigit():
      # if the marks are digits then turn them to integers
      new_marks = list(map(int, marks))

# loop and check that both first items of each list are bigger than the second items
# for instance that 90 and 70 are bigger than 20 and 50
# if that condition is true then substract 90 - 20 and 70 - 50

  print(new_marks)
```

Comment: Whereas the values are currently lists, do you propose to convert the values to single integers - e.g., ['90','20'] becomes 70. What happens if the first value in the list is lower than the second?

Comment: Do you really have strings in your dictionary?  Or are they in fact numbers?

Comment: @TomKarzes they are coming from a .txt file as strings so then I turn that list of strings to integers.

Comment: @DarkKnight I was gonna raise a ValueError once i could loop

Comment: So you are at the point where you have two numbers, new_marks[0] and new_marks[1] and you want to subtract them, but you don't know how? Have you tried just subtracting them? If you're trying to do something way too fancy with map, you probably want https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my suggestion for your question. In fact, there are many ways to manage out it. I've added some more values for testing other possible scenarios.

```
my_dict = {'101': ['90', '20'], '102': ['70', '50'], '103': ['err1'], '104': ['err1', 'err2'], '105': ['10', '20'], '106': ['20', 'err3']}
results = dict()
for(student, marks) in my_dict.items():
   try:
      score = int(marks[0]) - int(marks[1])
      results[student] = score if score > 0 else 0
   except ValueError as e:
      print('Values are not correct:{}'.format(e.args))
   except:
     raise()

for student, score in results.items():
   print('student {} has scored {}'.format(student, score))
```

Comment: Thank you Rui that works perfect and I can understand the logic.

Comment: Very interesting. So, if the sub-list is ['70','80'] the value changes to zero. How did you deduce that requirement from the question? Also, why *raise()* ? The only other possible exception is IndexError which you can eliminate by checking the length if the value (assuming it's a list)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to raise ValueError explicitly because that will happen naturally if the strings do not represent integers.

My interpretation of the issue leads to this:

```
_dict: dict[str, list[str]|int] = {'101': ['90', '20'], '102': ['70', '50']}

for k, v in _dict.items():
    if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 2:
        if (r := int(v[0]) - int(v[1])) > 0:
            _dict[k] = r

print(_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'101': 70, '102': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also run a dictionary comprehension with a conditional expression to check that the value is in fact a list and it .

```
>>> d = {'101': ['90', '20'], '102': ['70', '50']}
>>> {
...   k: [int(v[0]) - int(v[1])] \
...     if isinstance(v, list) and \
...       len(v) == 2 and \
...       v[0].isdigit() and \
...       v[1].isdigit() and \
...       int(v[0]) > int(v[1]) \
...     else v 
...   for k, v in d.items()
... }
{'101': [70], '102': [20]}
```